# Is it possible to generate custom bit.ly URLs through their API?

Tags: api, bit.ly, url-shortener

I would like to be able to generate custom bit.lys (`http://bit.ly/thecakeisalie` type things) through their API.  This does not appear to be possible, but I thought I'd check; does anyone happen to know otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was removed from the API. I like many others were trying to do this and bit.ly's support email replied saying it has been removed. Similar experiences on their ApiDocumentation wiki [here](http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation).

Comment: Is it able to update an existing short url with a different long url?

Answer (score 7):

This unfortunately had to be removed for our free users due to on-going abuse.  All of the custom bitlinks on bit.ly are created in the same key space, so allowing for automated creation there quickly leads to there being no sane options availble for anybody else.

That being said, we have recently added the ability for our [paid customers](https://bitly.com/a/features) to create [custom bitlinks](https://bitly.com/a/features) if they are using a custom domain.  In this case, our customers get their own key space so creating custom bitlinks en-mass isn't a problem.

Comment: Thanks for providing some context. Two follow-up questions: 

 1. Can *paid* customers create custom bitlinks only on their own domain or on the bit.ly domain too?
 2. Can *paid* customers use the API to create custom bitlinks?

Comment: Hey @SeanOC why isn't this in the documentation?  And why can paying customers NOT create them via the API?